# xna creating game stage management contrls

Tags: xna, c#, architecture

I am under planning stage of my game where I am creating controls for my game. I have create below control for stages but have no idea how this we can achieve in xna.
[image]

Please also help me with your views regarding how to load, play multiple stages and persist score for each stage in game using xna. What we normally used to do is just put everything in infinite loop but here I want more intelligence in game, as one stage over it should go back to menu. Example can be something like angry bird stages.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting point is to look at the Game State Management tutorial provided by Microsoft here:
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

In that example, you *can* create and use global variables in the ScreenManager class for score etc. This would provide a simple method of persisting across the various states.

Comment: but how can I create above control in xna. I have already checked it out the game state management sample.

Comment: Try this coverflow example on Codeplex:   http://funcworksxna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CoverFlowSelector%20class&referringTitle=Documentation   It has an Ms-Pl license, so you are able to reuse the code as you want